# How to get two columns or panels in one explorer window in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Is it possible to have to panels or windows with independent folders in one Explorer window?

This is easily achievable in KDE or Gnome and has NEVER been implemented in Windows. Is there any plugin like that or other option to achieve that?

I want Explorer to work like total commander, dolphin or nautilus. Possible?

Answer (score 5):

Choose on of the five ways below:

### Mouse maniac

Grab one windows to left and the other window to right until screen edges and Windows Explorer will autoresize them to fill the entire screen;

### Keyboard supercombo

Select one window and press the combo Win+Arrow left, and select the other window and press the combo Win+Arrow right. You will earn more reputation points if you use Alt+Tab combo to alternate between windows;

### Old school

Right click on taskbar and choose to organize windows as you want (I think it is witten as "tile" or "side-by-side", because I use it in Portuguese). In Windows 7, you can do it minimizing all windows (or Win+M), restoring only the windows you want to tile (with mouse or Alt+Tab) and then right clicking on taskbar and choosing the option to organize. If you are truly old school using Windows XP, you can select which windows to organize on taskbar using ctrl key and left clicking on them, or selecting a taskbar group, and organize them with right mouse button option;

### 3rd party explorer

Try xplorer²;

### 3rd party windows manager

Try Moab's solution, Q-Dir.

Answer (score 1):

Try Q-Dir, its free

http://q-dir.en.softonic.com/

It can be configured for 2 windows if you don't need 4.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

i grab one explorer window, ditch it to the left side of the screen so it maximizes in the left side of the screen.

then i grab another explorer window and ditch it to the right side of the screen .. so it maximizes in the right half of the screen.

consider this "totalcommander for the poort".